# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord query select only column string field value with where clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I was wondering if there is a way to use a select statement with a where clause similar to this way that does not seem to work for me in Ruby version 2.0/Rails 4.0 trying to retrieve a single record string value of a city where the building name is a certain name:

```
building_city = Building.select(:city).where(building_name: building).uniq
```

I have also tried:

```
building_city = Building.select(:city).where(building_name: building).distinct
```

Currently I have my code working like this:

```
building_city = Building.where(building_name: building).first
```

This grabs an entire Building object, and then I can call the city by doing a:

```
building_city.city
```

This works fine with what I am trying to achieve, but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this.  Specifically, I was wondering if there is a way to grab only the string value of a city where the building name equals a certain building and store it into a variable?

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for `pluck`? Something like:

```
cities = Building.where(building_name: building).uniq.pluck(:city)
```

That will perform this SQL:

```
select distinct city from buildings where building_name = '...'
```

and give you the cities as an array of strings. You'll still get an array but a quick `first` call will take care of that if you're certain that there will only be one entry.

Comment: Sorry... just wanted to clarify my follow up question, which is what is the difference between .shift and .first in this context?  Does it matter?

Comment: If you have an array then `shift` modifies the array, `first` gives you `arr[0]` without modifying `arr`. If you're working with an ActiveRecord relation then `first` will, more or less, throw a `LIMIT 1` on the query and only pull out one object.

Comment: cool I appreciate your feedback and will mark your answer as the correct solution for me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`building_city = Building.select(:city, :building_name).where(building_name: building).uniq` — you need to include the `building_name`

Comment: that did not work for me.  Sorry.  It output nothing?  Is there a trick to getting it to print?  What kind of object did you expect that to store?

Answer (score 0):

```rb
city = Building.where(building_name: building).pick(:city)
```

Rails 6 introduced `pick` method with works like `where(..).pluck(..).first`. [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pick)